# porting g++ code to Clang++ issue

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, llvm-clang

Following code is a hypothetical code. This is a perfectly valid code under g++ (4.2.1). When compiled with Clang++ (4.2) it produces error as `qualified reference to 'myclass' is a constructor name rather than a type wherever a constructor can be declared`

```
class myclass
{
public:
    myclass() { }
    ~myclass() {}

};

myclass::myclass* funct() {
    return new myclass();
}
```

I could fix this by changing `myclass::myclass*` to `myclass*`. However I am not expected to change any code. Is there any commandline flags that I could provide in order to compile this code as is using Clang++ ?

Comment: the code is not standards compliant the way it is so i'm surprised it compiles on g++ st all. i would change it.

Comment: `myclass` is a type. `myclass::myclass` is not.

Comment: g++ 4.2.1 is what, 7 years old?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such flag : since this program is ill-formed, it should not compile.

If a compiler compiles it, then it is a compiler bug. [This bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11764) looks like the one impacting your particular gcc version.

The code should be fixed to :

```
myclass* funct() {
    return new myclass();
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, `class myclass::myclass* funct()` is also legal, though I can't see any reason why someone would want to do that.

Comment: @T.C hehe yes right. Adding it to the answer would only confuse readers, I believe... feel free to edit though.

Comment: The relevant GCC bug is [11764](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11764). Also, technically `class myclass::myclass::myclass::myclass::myclass::myclass *` is legal too :D

Comment: @T.C report added thanks for sharing (how did you find it so quickly ?)

Comment: There's only a handful of bugs when I searched for "injected class name" in closed bugs.

Answer (score 3):

gcc 4.9.1 also rejects the code:

```
 error: ‘myclass::myclass’ names the constructor, not the type
```

Unless the code base is happy with the rather old gcc 4.2, I see no alternative than to fix the code.